Google App Script How to use projects.deployments.delete
I developed a Google Sheets extension and deployed the JavaScript code.
Unfortunately, I unintentionally ended up creating multiple deployments.
Despite my efforts to find a solution for deleting the unwanted deployments, I couldn’t find any assistance.
If you could provide a sample code demonstrating how to use the projects.deployments.delete method, it would be greatly appreciated.
Ref : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/delete
